# Improve computers ability to guess in player vs computer number game

Tags: python

Below is a working code for a 2 player game that asks a user for a number input and the program suggests higher or lower. After each user turn, the computer will pick a random number and also receive a higher or lower suggestion. The game will continue until either user or computer input the correct number. It works just fine but I'm trying to find a way to make the computer listen to the higher or lower suggestion. Currently it just picks another random number with no adherence to the printed response. I thought about rewriting the computers part to something like:
if cg > the_number:
   print(cg - cg/2)
elif cg < the_number:
   print(cg + cg/2)
But all this did was start causing syntax errors and such. The question then is how to improve the 'AI' to somehow adjust it's response based on being higher or lower than the_number and where does that get input into the code text?

```
import random

name = input("Hello Player! What is your name? ")
print("Hello, ", name + "!")
print("Welcome to 'Guess the Number'!")
print("Your goal is to guess the number in as few tries as possible.")
print("And don't let the computer beat you! Good luck!")


the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = -1
tries = 1

while guess != the_number:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower!\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Higher!\n")
    else:
        break
    cg = random.randint(1, 100)
    print("The computer guessed: " + str(cg))
    tries += 1
    if cg > the_number:
        print("Too high Computer.\n")
    elif cg < the_number:
        print("Too low Computer.\n")
    else:
        break

if cg == the_number:
    print("The number was " + str(the_number) + ". " \
          + "Skynet wins, John Connor.")
    print("And it took you both", tries, "tries.\n")
    if tries <= 10:
        print("Hey you guys are good!")
    elif tries <= 15:
        print("A decent effort, but could be better.")
    else:
        print("Wow you guys are really bad at this xD") 
else:
    print("You win " + name + "! " + "The number was" + " " + str(the_number))
    print("And it took you both", tries, "tries.\n")
    if tries <= 10:
        print("Hey you guys are good!")
    elif tries <= 15:
        print("A decent effort, but could be better.")
    else:
        print("Wow you guys are really bad at this xD")



input("\n\n\t\tPress Enter to exit")
```

Comment: You have three numbers: The upper bound, the lower bound, and your guess.  (The bounds will get closer as you eliminate parts of the range).  The most efficient strategy is to execute binary search by always guessing the midpoint between your last guess and the indicated bound.  You should be saving whether or not the guess was too high in a variable, which you pass to a function for getting the midpoint, along with the bounds.

Comment: Ahhh ok this is making some sense. I am starting to see what I'm missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have the higher and lower bounds change with each hint, like so:

```
the_number = random.randint(1, 100)
guess = -1
tries = 1

lower_bound = 1
higher_bound = 100

while guess != the_number:
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))
    tries += 1
    if guess > the_number:
        print("Lower!\n")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("Higher!\n")
    else:
        break
    cg = random.randint(lower_bound, higher_bound)
    print("The computer guessed: " + str(cg))
    tries += 1
    if cg > the_number:
        higher_bound = cg - 1
        print("Too high Computer.\n")
    elif cg < the_number:
        lower_bound = cg + 1
        print("Too low Computer.\n")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Worked perfect! It's so simple when you finally see it. Thank you!